# Combining objects in a list. Python

Tags: python, list, object

I know how to combine objects with .append and .extend ect, but I can't figure out all all how to combine individual objects in a list into one object.

Example.

How would I change this list:
List = ["h","e","l","l","o"]

Into this list:
List = ["hello"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can be easily done with

```
["".join(list)]
```

For other uses, you can replace "" with any character that you wish to be the delimeter. For example

```
my_list = ["these", "should", "be", "separated", "by", "commas"]
print ",".join(my_list)
```

will output

```
"these,should,be,separated,by,commas"
```

Comment: I think the exact answer is `["".join(list)]`

Comment: Oops, yes it is. Editted